# R functional programming to read directory and specific number of files with a particular extention

Tags: r, loops, functional-programming

**I want to do the following using function and loops in R:**

1. Read the directory address from user input (if empty input, warn user to provide correct address, repeat loop and exit if user chooses option 'X').
2. If address of directory is correctly give (e.g. C:/MyDirectory/MySubDirectory), select folder and check the extensions of the files. Suppose there are two '.txt', one '.xlsx' and two '.csv' files in that folder, ask user which files to read from which extension?

**What I tried:**

```
input <- NULL
while (input != "X" | input != "x" | !is.null(input)){
   input <- readline("Please enter the full path for your files, if you want to exit, enter 'X': ") 
   # Set default directory to the address provided by user
   setwd(input)

   if(input == 'X' | input == 'x'){
      cat("\nYou Chose to exit, Bye!\n")
      exit -1
    }
} 

   FilesListCSV <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", ignore.case=TRUE)
   FilesListXLSX <- list.files(pattern="*.xlsx", ignore.case=TRUE)
   FilesListTXT <- list.files(pattern="*.txt", ignore.case=TRUE)
   cat("There are ", length(FilesListCSV), " CSV file(s), ", length(FilesListXLSX), 
   " Excel File(s), and ", length(FilesListTXT), " Text File(s) in the folder.\n"

   while (opt != "1" | opt != "2" | opt != "3" | !is.null(opt)){
   cat("\nPlease choose extention to read files [1. for CSV, 2. for XLSX, 3. for TXT files.\n")

    opt <- readline("Enter Your Option : ")
   # Example code for reading csv files
   if (opt == "1") {
       library(dplyr)
       library(readr)

       read_file <- list.files(pattern = "*.csv") %>% 
           lapply(read.csv, stringsAsFactors=F) %>% 
           bind_rows 
      }

   }
```

**Problems:**

1. in the above code, While loop is throwing following error:

   Error in while (input != "X" | input != "x" | !is.null(input)) { : 
    argument is of length zero
2. My code seems to be messy, do not know how to make it simple.

**Can someone please help me?**

Comment: @chinsoon12, yes i tried that one as well. still error.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Yes! it worked. at least for while loop.

Answer (score 0):

To your first part, What about:

```
input <- NULL
while(length(input) == 0){
    input <- readline("Please enter the full path for your folder, \nif you want to exit, 
                       enter 'X' (without quote): ") 
    if(input == 'X' | input == 'x'){
       cat("\nYou Chose to exit, Bye!\n")
       return
    } else {

    # Set default directory to the address provided by user
    setwd(input)
    }
 }
```

Comment: it works well.. thanks. I am hoping for the second answer.